# añadir a un panel ButtonGroup y JRadioButtons mediante metodos

Tags: java

Dispongo de 2 métodos, uno que me genera `JRadioButtons` los almacena en un `arraylist` y me devuelve el elemento según la posición del indice y otro que me genera un `ButtonGroup`, he probado  varias maneras y no doy con la tecla para añadir los `Jradios` al `buttonGroup` y añadirlos al panel, a continuación os dejo el código, haber si podéis arrojar algo de luz al tema,

**Vista**

```
  public JRadioButton bornradios(int index){
     radios.add(new JRadioButton());
     return radios.get(index);
    }
    public ButtonGroup borndivradios(JRadioButton r){
       buttongroup.add(r);
       return buttongroup;
    }
```

CONTROLADOR

La linea esta es la genera el error, como podéis observar tengo otro método en vista que me devuelve un panel del `array` de paneles según su indice, el error en concreto es el siguiente: [image: ERROR] Si tenéis alguna recomendación de como podría lograrlo lo agradecería.

Comment: vista es una istancia de mi clase vista: private vista vista= new vista(); y el metodo en sí me retorna uno de los panels de mi array de paneles el cual se llama panels, nose si fuera necesario compartir el codigo completo pero si así lo fuera dimelo, gracias :     public JPanel getindexpanels(int index) {
        return panels.get(index);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `ButtonGroup` no es un componente, y no puede ser añadido a un `JPanel` (puesto que **NO** es un componente) por medio del método `add(...);`.

`ButtonGroup` en términos simples, te permite elegir cualquier objeto (que sean botones), para que al momento de seleccionar uno, los demás automáticamente se deseleccionen. Sólo en forma de información, y como indica la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html), no tendría sentido hacer un grupo con `JButton` o con `JMenuItem`, sin embargo este no es tu caso.

Lo que debes hacer es añadir directamente el `JRadioButton` al `JPanel`.

Básicamente algo como esto:

```
JRadioButton radiobutton = vista.bornradios(0); // Se crea el JRadioButton
vista.borndivradios(radiobutton); // Se añade el JRadioButton al ButtonGroup
vista.getindexpanels(0).add(radiobutton); // Se añade el JRadioButton al JPanel
```